# Singular they: Is it proper?

Tags: pronouns, singular-they

In one of my answers here, I used the singular they:

> When someone orders a rouge, **they** mean red wine which in French translates to le vin rouge.

My question is, is it right for me to use *they*? Or since I used *someone* at the beginning, is it imperative for me to use *he* or *she*?

Any insights?

Comment: Yes, perfectly fine.

Comment: Please [search the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22singular%20they%22) before asking. Typing a two-word search string gets you the answer much faster than typing up an entire question. We even have a [dedicated tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singular-they?sort=votes&pageSize=15) with 50+ questions.